# Is there an easy way to print (to a text file) the path of all 'References' in a .NET project?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there an easy way to print (to a text file) the path of all 'References' in a .NET project?

In the IDE, one could see the path of each, but if I want that printed for all references in a project, do you know how can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the csproj file (assuming it's a C# project you will find something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v10.2, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\Libs\DevExpress.Data.v10.2.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  <Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v10.2.Linq, Version=10.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>..\Libs\DevExpress.Data.v10.2.Linq.dll</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
  <!-- some more -->
</ItemGroup>
```

You could read the project file as a XML document and fire up some XPath queries and do a Console.Writeline.

Comment: Looking in my csproj file, I could not fint the HintPath. My porject is a Console application with DBContext EF. I can only see the names for the reference but not the path (which I also need). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It might be, that if it's installed in the Global Assembly Cache or another well known path, a hint path is not needed. Did you added EF using nuget or using add reference dialog?

Comment: Thanks for your followup, you have a good point regading GAC. I added EF manually using the add reference dialog.

Comment: I will consider this question answered - Thank you for your help.